# createAnimatedSwitchNavigator undefined is not a function

Tags: android, react-native, npm, undefined-function

I am developing a react native app. In that app, I am trying to use an NPM package called

> createAnimatedSwitchNavigator

But when I try to run the program I am getting the following error

> undefined is not a function (evaluating '(0
>   _reactNavigationAnimatedSwitch.createAnimatedSwitchNavigator)')

Below is my code

NB:- the normal SwitchNavigator is working fine with this code

```
            import {createAnimatedSwitchNavigator,
                createAppContainer} from 'react-navigation-animated-switch';

            import Login   from "./Login/Login";
            import SignUp  from './SignUp/SignUp';

            const Navigate = createAnimatedSwitchNavigator({
            Login:         {screen:Login},
            SignUp:        {screen:SignUp},
            },
            )

            export const AppContainer = createAppContainer(Navigate)
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it using the following method

```
import createAnimatedSwitchNavigator from 'react-navigation-animated-switch';
import {createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
```